# AnyLogic wait-block, block condition available?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

In my simulation I have different types of resources. At the start of my simulation I define several parameters to the different resources (machines). I want a predefined number of agents (e.g. 50) to run through my resource, so I chose to use a wait block inside my resources. So if there are more than 50 agents inside this resource, the wait block should release all 50 agents at once and block afterwards immediately.
The code in the wait block looks like this: [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwDMH.jpg)

So if an agent with the attribute `machine1` comes into the resource and if the condition `self.size() == 50` isn't true yet, the program jumps to the default case instead of staying in case `machine1` until this condition is true. Is there some code for an possible else-Block, something like "`self.stayInWaitBlockUntilIfConditionIsTrue`"? Or another solution for my problem maybe with hold blocks? Didn't find something on AnyLogic help page.

Comment: Inside `case machine1:`, if you put an else statement saying `else {break;}`, does it work?

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks Ahmadov. Litte embarrassed that the solution would be so simple...

Comment: glad to help! I will write this as answer, please also upvote.

Comment: Since I haven't been on SOW long, I'm not allowed to upvote yet, but I will for sure do when I'm allowed to! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `case machine1:`, if you put an else statement saying `else {break;}`, it should work.